# MySQL Stored procedure with input and output parameters not working with string input

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure with two varchar input parameters and one int output parameter.  The idea is that I pass in the table name and an unique string,  check the table to see if that string already exists in the table and return the id of that record if it does.  Currently the sproc looks like:

```
BEGIN 
SET @getID = CONCAT('SELECT `id` as id_Out FROM ',tablename_In,' WHERE `formSecret`=',formSecret_In);
PREPARE stmt FROM @getID; 
EXECUTE stmt; 
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt; 
END
```

If I pass in a number, everything works and I get a record id.  If I pass in a full alpha-numeric string (which is what the unique ID's are), it fails, telling me that the column does not exist.

For example: `call sp_GetRecordID(123456,'tbl_justsaythanks',@id_Out);` will return a record ID just like I want.

But if I try a real id from the table that's a string...

```
`call sp_GetRecordID('fc66d9a82ba717e0931462370e64baff','tbl_justsaythanks',@id_Out);`
```

I get "Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'fc66d9a82ba717e0931462370e64baff' in 'where clause'"

Since I'm new to MySQL, I'm not sure where I'm off on this - I suspect it has something to do with the application of tick marks in the query to designate the columns but I can't see it at the moment.

So, any help in pointing me the right way would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to swap your two input parameters:   call sp_GetRecordID('tbl_justsaythanks','fc66d9a82ba717e0931462370e64baff',@id_Out);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a stored procedure like the following:

```sql
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_GetRecordID`;

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_GetRecordID`(
  `tablename_In` VARCHAR(64),
  `formSecret_In` VARCHAR(32),
  OUT `id_Out` BIGINT UNSIGNED
)
BEGIN
  SET @`query` := CONCAT('SELECT `id` INTO @`id_Out`
                          FROM ', `tablename_In` ,' 
                          WHERE `formSecret` = \'', `formSecret_In`, '\'');
  PREPARE `stmt` FROM @`query`;
  EXECUTE `stmt`;
  SET `id_Out` := @`id_Out`,
       @`query` := NULL;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE `stmt`;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/doSM1UNAiZ47C7XKZ4wdN8/0) example.

Comment: Sir - that absolutely rocks and is exactly what I need.  There's a lot of dreck out there so it's fabulous to get something done the right way to build off of.